# AWS RDS SQL Server Instance, Question in Maintenance Plan

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

New to cloud and have questions on AWS RDS  SQL Server Instance, Question in Maintenance Plan.

As a DBA team we are expecting RDS access and admin access on SQL box. But was limited with setupadmin and process admin. Not able to see the error log even.

I don't even see the maintenance plan under management.

Questions:

1. Why limiting access? since we are not the DBAs for these servers?
2. Do we need to set up regular backups(full, log) for the user databases of AWS will be taking care of it?
3. How about the user database maintenance like index maintenance and update stats?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 3):

> Why limiting access? since we are not the DBAs for these servers?

Amazon RDS is a Platform-as-a-Service offering, meaning the vendor is taking care of the infrastructure and platform setup, deployment and management. In order to secure and stabilise the managed platform, you're restricted in what access you have.

You do not have higher privileged access because A) you do not require it, higher privilege tasks are handled by the vendor, and B) it would represent a security and/or stability risk for the vendor to expose these higher privileges to you.

> Do we need to set up regular backups(full, log) for the user databases
> of AWS will be taking care of it?

AWS RDS for SQL Server features automatic backups by default. See the FAQ section [Backup and Restore](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/sqlserver/faqs/?nc=sn&loc=6). By default, backups are only retained for 7 days, however, your AWS admins can increase this to align with your organisations data retention policies.

> How about the user database maintenance like index maintenance and
> update stats?

Optimisation tasks like Index Maintenance will not be taken care of by the vendor, however, AWS RDS does allow you access to deploy [SQL Server Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.CommonDBATasks.Agent.html) jobs. You could deploy Ola Hallengren's T-SQL based [SQL Server Maintenance Solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) and schedule it via Agent jobs to handle index & statistics maintenance.

Here is a link to AWS documentation for some [common SQL Server DBA tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.CommonDBATasks.html) in AWS RDS.